# Is there a script add on or browser addon that will re-enable headlines on tweets?

Tags: scripting, twitter, browser-extension

Twitter has removed all headlines from tweets, leaving only images and base URL names visible. Is there any script or add-on that could re-enable headline visibility?

Answer (score 0):

https://reddit.com/r/Twitter/comments/170l9hf/browser_extension_to_add_headlines_link_previews/

This has done the trick for me. Not on the extension store for Chrome yet, but it's trivial to install manually.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is free, works in Chrome and brings the headlines back (recommended via [waxy.org](https://waxy.org/2023/10/control-panel-for-twitter/))

https://jbscript.dev/control-panel-for-twitter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: boo to bots ....